# Engine oil temperature

Tags: dodge, temperature, journey

I have a 2017 Dodge Journey ( fiat ) 2.4L

I bought this a few months back and I noticed during the winter months there was some yellow residue that would accumulate on the oil fill cap, unfortunately a powertrain warranty doesnt cover head gaskets, so I guess I'll just have to wait until the engine breaks down.

But that just caused me to pay more attention to the new "oil temperature gauge", after driving just 30 miles my oil temperature was reading 199, my coolant temperature was 197 and my transmission fluid was 105

Are these normal reading for such a short distance, I would of thought the oil and coolant combined to dissipate the heat wouldn't let it past 150 but then again, that's why I'm here.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why "a powertrain warranty doesnt cover head gaskets" ... The engine is the heart of the powertrain. If someone told you it isn't covered, they are lying to you. If a head gasket goes bad while under a powertrain warranty, it should be covered (unless the warranty isn't worth the paper it's written on). I'm not saying the small amount of residual gunk on the inside of the oil cap is a blown head gasket. I am however saying not to be fooled into thinking a head gasket isn't part of the powertrain.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 some information https://www.endurancewarranty.com/learning-center/extended-warranty/what-is-a-drivetrain-warranty/ it looks like a powertrain warranty do cover head gasket but drivetrain warranty does not.

Comment: @trondhansen - Seems the OP stated "powertrain" ... wondering your point?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 it looks to me like the OP have been misinformed about what is covered by the warranty,I hope it is okay for me to agree with you in what you say in your comment.

Comment: @trondhansen - Makes sense, read in that light. Thank you!

Comment: I called the Dodge dealer and they told me it wasnt covered under a powertrain warranty, I also reviewed this website https://www.carchex.com/content/what-does-a-powertrain-warranty-cover which says the head gasket wont be covered if its simply leaking, what else would a head gasket be doing 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The yellow residue is common and normal.  It's water from condensation and it easily happens when there are cold periods followed by warmer and more humid periods.

It's only when there is a huge amount of this coupled with water/coolant in your oil that you have evidence of a problem.

The best solution is to drive the vehicle for an hour or two regularly to allow the engine heat to drive out the excess moisture and to change the oil per the manufacturer's recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

The temparatures is normal,coolant temparature is 197F=91C so this is spot on what it should be.

Oil temparature is fine too,it is often a bit higher than the coolant temparature and this is normal.

The transmissiom fluid temparature is fine and it show your transmission is in good shape,105F=40C it is in the low range so no need to worry.

A tiny bit of gunk under the oil cap is normal if you only drive short trips so i do not think you can expect the head gasket to fail any time soon.